# Correctly use of imageBuilder in Image class (not Image.network)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a grid view showing several images on one page. During loading, I'm trying to use the `loadingBuilder` in an `Image` widget to show a `CircularProgressIndicator` and the loading process.

I want in each tile of the grid view a separate progress indicator, and not all spinning at once.
If I use the `loadingBuilder` in `Image.network(...)`, all works as expected like this:

**Test with Image.network(...)**

[image]

```dart
child: Image.network(boulderList[index].image, fit: BoxFit.cover,
  loadingBuilder:(BuildContext context, Widget child,ImageChunkEvent loadingProgress) {
    if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
    return Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
        valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(GLOBALS.difficultyMap[boulderList[index].difficulty]),
        value: loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes != null ?
        loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded / loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes
            : null,
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

---

**Test with Image(...)**

If I use the `loadingBuilder` in `Image(...)` it doesn't show me the progress indicators. It also loads the images one after the other, but the tiles of the grid view are not showing the progress indicators. This is the code I tried:

```dart
child: Image(
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
  loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget child, ImageChunkEvent loadingProgress) {
    if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
    return Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
        valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(GLOBALS.difficultyMap[boulderList[index].difficulty]),
        value: loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes != null
            ? loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded / loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes
            : null,
      ),
    );
  },
  image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
    boulderList[index].image,
  ),
),
```

So why I'm not using the Image.network? Simple: I want to cache the images; therefore I want to use `CachedNetworkImageProvider` in the image `property`

---

What I also tried was to keep it simple, only using a `CachedNetworkImage` as following. Unfortunately there, I have all the progress indicators spinning at once, like this:

[image]

```dart
CachedNetworkImage(
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
  placeholder: (context, url) => Center(
    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
  ),
  imageUrl: boulderList[index].image,
),
```

**So short question:**
How can I use the `loadingBuilder` in the `Image` class correctly, without using `Image.network`

**Update**
Apparently the problem is the `CachedNetworkImageProvider`, because if I use another image Provider in the `image:` property like `NetworkImage`, the progress indicators are shown. The question is now, why the Image's `loadingBuilder` acts differently on which provider is used in the `image:` property

Comment: seems that `CachedNetworkImageProvider` does not update the progress of data already loaded

Comment: But it also doesn't show the progress indicators on the first load, when the images arn't cached. But I the problem seems to be the `CachedNetworkImageProvider`. Because if I use another Provider e.g. NetworkImage, then everything works fine

Comment: I agree: cachednetworkimageprovider seems to be broken